# Cakephp 2.x URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I think somehow most of us had a trouble with .htaccess I d'like to know if someone can help me.
Opensuse 12.3 :
Code:

```
Linux linux-hyo0.site 3.7.10-1.16-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 31 20:21:23 UTC 2013 (97c14ba) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I d'like to install Cakephp on my machine but I have an error on my webpage saying that "
Code:
**URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.**
"

my /etc/sysconfig/apache2 file as this : 
Code:

```
APACHE_MODULES="authz_host actions alias auth_basic authz_groupfile authn_file authz_user autoindex cgi dir include log_config mime negotiation setenvif status userdir asis imagemap php5 reqtimeout authz_default rewrite"
```

and the /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf as this line at the end
Code:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module                 /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

I did also change my file etc/apache2/defaul-server.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any help?

on app/webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and on app/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure the .htaccess file is present?

Comment: Hello M. CJThomson, Yes I downloade it via git so both files (.htaccess) are in there folder (/app .htaccess and app/webroot .htaccess) I haven't modified them yet.

Comment: What's the htaccess file look like?

Comment: Hi! Jin!
I will answer you on my post.. cause my code is ugly in this tiny textarea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite an old question but maybe this answer is relevant for you Google users out there:

Did you change the View/Layouts/default.ctp?

This is what happens with this warning:

- The warning is set in a div in View/Pages/home.ctp
- In home.ctp only sets the warning when the file app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css exists
- In the standard default.ctp layout, the stylesheet /css/cake.generic.css is loaded
- In cake.generic.css the div with the warning is.... hidden!!!

So what happens when the default home page loads: it tries to load the cake.generic.css style sheet, which succeeds when mod_rewrite is configured correctly. So then the warning is hidden. If it fails to load the style sheet, the warning will stay visible.

This warning pops up, in short, when either there is a problem with mod_rewrite and htaccess, *or you changed the layout so that the cake.generic.css is no longer loaded*...

First check if you even try to load the stylesheet. Does it show up in your F12 console?

Answer (score 2):

After hours trying to track down the problem I finally found that my .htaccess file never existed in the first place. I copied the following code into a new .htaccess file and hey presto.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me first say: I HATE CAKEPHP!!!!
I just spent hours working on this issue.
I learned that cake tests URL rewrite by checking for app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css
Make sure that exists.
My solution came after I checked the apache error_log and saw it complaining about not being able to find http:/myproject/css.  Well, there is no css directory there by default.  I created a link (ln -s app/webroot/css) and it solved Cake's problem.

Comment: I dont hate cake.. but your answer helped to get to the problem...
I never had this problem earlier though...

Comment: You should not hate CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you got this error after new installation of Cakephp and you do not changed any of the files(css files or cake.generic.css) then do the following:

1. sudo a2enmod rewrite
2. sudo service apache2 restart
3. sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
4. Look for “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” and add the following lines directly below:

   AllowOverride All
5. sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change all AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

I have this problem and solve this copying the lines of cakebook:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also a .htaccess file in the root folder, i.e. /.htaccess. This may not have been copied across as it's hidden by default by most operating systems.

Try adding this as the contents of /.htaccess and checking it makes it to the web server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

There's more explanation at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Answer (score -1):

There’s two solutions:

1) Either set the `DocumentRoot` in your Apache configuration file to the **app/webroot/** directory, and CakePHP will use the **.htaccess** file there.

2) Place a **.htaccess** file in the root of your application, as by default I don’t think one gets created if you use the CakePHP console to generate an app. That **.htaccess** file should look this this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/     [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```